# JFactory stopped working in Joomla 3.8, what now?

Tags: jfactory, joomla3.8

A client called today lamenting that our automated mail (they fill a form and we mail them a code) is not working.

Of course, this is because my code still has the JFactory class and is looking for...

```
require ('libraries/joomla/factory.php');
```

...which is no more since Joomla 3.8

I have seen [this answer to a similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46418148), but `getMailer` is not named in the linked Github file.

**What should I use instead of the following lines?**

```
require ('libraries/joomla/factory.php'); #I suppose nothing
$mail = JFactory::getMailer(); #I have no idea
```

Of course I'm instantiating the `$mail` object with everything needed to use

```
$mail->Send();
```

So if that won't work anymore I'd appreciate some guidance.

Comment: Welcome to JSE. Are you trying to load `JFactory` outside of Joomla? Are you getting any errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked for JFactory instead of looking for getMailer or factory.php in the class conversion chart mentioned in the answer linked in the question and solved this problem myself:

```
$mail = \joomla\CMS\factory::getMailer();
```

Require is not... required anymore.